# Ada + PolyORB : can I have multiple instances of the same RCI unit and be able to call a specific one from code?

Tags: distributed, ada

I'm developing a distributed application using Ada's Distributed System Annex and PolyORB and I have a somewhat peculiar request.

Let's say I have a RCI (Remote Call Interface) unit called `U` and the main program called `MAIN` that uses it.

What I want to know is:

1. Can I configure DSA to create multiple copies of the partition `U` ?
2. If the answer is yes, can I then call a specific one of these
       partitions from my code in `MAIN`?

I can't find info on this online, right now the only solution I can think of would be to have a pre-processor generate multiple "copies" of `U` from a generic template and patch the DSA configuration file accordingly. Is there a less "hacky" way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading all the documentation I could find, I conclude that this is not possible, ie: it's not contemplated in DSA.

I still think the hacky solution I proposed in my original question would work, however it doesn't make much sense from a practical point of view.

For my application, I decided to switch to SOAP, using the `AWS` web server and ditching DSA altogether.

EDIT: in response to shark8 comment:

My idea, in detail, was this. Let's assume I have some kind of configuration file in which I describe how many copies of the partitions I want and how each one is configured, here's how I'd do it:

1. Have a pre-processor read the configuration file and generate source files for all the needed
   partitions from a template (basically this would just create a copy
   of the files and alter the package name and file name to avoid
   collisions)
2. Have the pre-processor patch the DSA configuration file accordingly, to generate those partitions
3. I would then have one final package that acts as a "gateway", or a "selector" if you
   want, to the other packages. It would contain "generic" procedures
   that would act as selectors, something like:

   ```
       procedure Some_Procedure(partitionID : Integer; params : whatever) is
   case partitionID is
    when 1 =>
      Partition1.Some_Procedure(params);
    when 2 =>
      Partition2.Some_Procedure(params);
    etc...
   end case;
   ```

   end Some_Procedure;

Obviously, like the partitions themselves, the various lines in the case will have to be generated by the pre-processor. Also: the main program that calls this procedure needs to pass it's ID, but this is no problem since it will have read the same configuration as the preprocessor did at 1) so it would know the IDs and which one it wants to call, depending on its internal logic.

As I said, it's a tortuous method, but I think it should work.

Comment: Here's a question: how would you achieve #2?

Answer (score 0):

The DSA (polyorb) is very flexible and you can have multiple unique RCI . Why would you want to do this? is it a maximisation of processing speed. Having used the DSA quite a bit I would question your motives for doing this in this way and perhaps suggest that you change your design.

If its processing speed I would suggest you do your processing in multiple client partitions, and use the asynchronous messaging mechanism in the DSA. If you need more processing speed, then do your calculation/ processing in multiple stages across client partitions.

Theres a great example of this messaging mechanism in the banking example application included in the DSA examples.

Comment: Basically, I have a simulation in which I have several geographical areas which have to run each on it's own node. This is why I needed multiple "copies" (partitions) of the same pieces of code: each partition would represent one of this areas. From reading the examples I found, there didn't seem to be a way to do this, ie: have multiple, distinguishable instances of the same partition. Thus, I opted for a different solution. If there actually IS a method to do what I describe, I would still be interested in knowing it, so feel free to link the relevant documentation/examples

Comment: You could have a passive partition and a group of your code partitions each identified through a parameter you pass in to it through command line interface. DSA is great for this. I'm between projects at the moment, if you want some professional help, I am on google plus. Its not a huge job but its not trivial